# CQRS - Complex types

Tags: c#, cqrs, complextype

Following the CQRS pattern, is it allowed to add complex types inside the command? (See "Address"-class in example below)

```
public interface ICommand{}

public class RegisterNewUser: ICommand{
    public string FirstName {get;set;}
    public string LastName {get;set;}
    public List<Address> Addresses {get;set;}
}

public class Address{
    public string Street {get;set;}
    public string City {get;set;}
}

public class RegisterNewUserHandler: ICommandHandler<RegisterNewUser>{
    //Do some stuff
}
```

In my opinion, I would say yes... but I think I've seen others that say you're not allowed to do this.

Comment: Why wouldn't you be allowed to do this?

Comment: I think I read somewhere you're not allowed to use complex types... That you should  for example create the addresses first and then use their ID in the RegisterNewUser command. But that would seem to be much more work...

Comment: Also quite unsafe, let's look at it this way. We create the Adresses a User has and safe them successfully, but now our application crashes (for some unrelated reason) but we haven't created our Users yet. How are we supposed to know this? P.S a User having multiple Adresses doesn't really make sense, an Adress having multiple users makes more sense

Comment: Correct what you say. Thanks! (PS. I saw the example more as Billing and Shipping address) But the most important is that you understand what I mean ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, I believe it should be except if anyone has a good argument against this.

Let's look at it this way: We have a User signing up, he registers his three Adresses and clicks the save button triggering our command on the server-side. Great, our Application now splits up the creation into two commands, one saving the Adresses the other the actual person and links them.

Now, after saving our Adresses, our Application crashes (for some unrelated reason), oh no! We now have three Adresses saved in our Database but no User. Congrats, our Database now features dead data!

Comment: What about queries? Is it also allowed? (since no data is modified, and the problem you give as example here isn't applicable?)

Answer (score 1):

> Following the CQRS pattern, is it allowed to add complex types inside the command?

Yes.

Where it gets really complicated: trying to modify types that are stored in different places.

So, for example, if you are going to be storing changes to the user in the "user repository", and changes to the addresses in the "address repository", and you don't have some sort of guarantee that the repositories are going to be controlled by the same transaction, then you are going to start running into consistency problems.